# How can I express `find` conditions in MongoDB accessing document's values?

Tags: mongodb

For example, let's put the case I want all documents inside a collection which are inside a range, whose maximum value is inside the document itself:

```
myDocument {
   qty: Number,
   maxValue: Number,
}

db.collection.find( { field: { $gt: 0, $lt: maxValue } } );
```

Is it possible to do something like that in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, using $cmp and aggregation https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$project: {compareResult: {$cmp: ['$field','$maxValue']}}},
    {$match: {compareResult: -1, field: {$gt: 0}}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. And what if I would like to compare a date field with the result of a subtraction between the current date and a period expressed in microseconds? For example:
     
   `lastDate < (Date.now() - (60 * 60 * 2000))`

Comment: I have tested, there is no problem if you put `(Date.now() - (60 * 60 * 2000))` as second expression

Answer (score 0):

First, run this command to get max value of "maxValue" field

```
db.collection.find({},{maxValue:1}).sort({"maxValue":-1}).limit(1)
```

Let's assume max value is 3000.

Then run this

```
db.collection.find({"maxValue":{"$gte":0 ,"$lte":3000}})
```